# Why in React componentDidMount is called before handler is executed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I've got the following react code where the handler is called (because a Route is rendered in the render() function) after the componentDidMount. I would have thought componentDidMount would be called after the render happened and after the action method.

```
handler() {
    console.log('RouteCls:handler setting state true');
    this.setState({
        routeNotFound: true
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log('RoutesCls:cdm:' + this.state.routeNotFound);
    this.props.action(this.state.routeNotFound);
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/speakers" component={Speakers}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route render={props => <RouteNotFound action={this.handler}  />}></Route>
            </Switch>
            <div> in RoutesCls: { JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2) }</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve,

Answer (score 0):

comonentDidMount is called immediately after the render() function as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and [here](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/). All functions get called after that.